# Using the datafilter parameter in an .ajax query using javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm performing a search using the jQuery .ajax function but I need to filter the results to get rid of some code that's generated from the search. The CMS I'm using wraps all content in a body tag, etc. I need to grab just the contents of a specific div and load it into my target div. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#submitQuery').click(function(){

$.ajax({
url: '/Default.aspx?CCID=18511&FID=101997&ExcludeBoolFalse=True&PageID=10212140',
type: "POST",
data: "CAT_Custom_300770="+tags1,
success: function(data2) {
$('#results').append(data2);
},          
dataFilter: function(data) {
return $(data).find('.queryResults')[0];
$('#results').append(data);
}
});

<div id="results"></div>
```

The code on the results page that I'm trying to load into the #results div is:

```
<div class="queryResults">(Results go here) </div>
```

The CMS adds a bunch of extra code like links to standard style sheets, body tags, etc.

What I'm trying to do is bring only the contents of the .queryResults div and load it into the #results div.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but why use the datafilter for that?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Default.aspx?CCID=18511&FID=101997&ExcludeBoolFalse=True&PageID=10212140',
    type: "POST",
    data: "CAT_Custom_300770="+tags1,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#results').append($('.queryResults',data));
    }       
});
```

Comment: That's not working for some reason. Nothing is being appended to the #results div.